# HikCentral Professional Authentication Issue - Invalid signature

Tags: authentication, camera, signature

I am working on a project with integrating with HikCentral by HikVision and I am having some problems while trying to HTTP Rest API to the HikCentral Server.

While trying to create the signature and using the appKey and the secretKey in the request I keep getting this response:

```
{
    "code": "0x02401003",
    "msg": "Invalid Signature! and StringToSign: POST\n*/*\napplication/json\n/artemis/api/common/v1/version"
}
```

I investigated a lot about how the credentials should be handled and encrypted with no success.
I tried also to put this in the pre request script in postman:

```
var appSecret = "appSecret";
var textToSign = "POST"+"\n"+"application/json"+"\n"+"application/json;charset=UTF-8"+"\n"+"/artemis/api/resource/v1/vehicle/vehicleList";
console.log(textToSign);
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(textToSign, appSecret);
var signature = hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
pm.environment.set("SIGNATURE", signature);
```

As I read in one of the answers here in stackoverflow, still no success.

Hope to understand what I am doing wrong in this situation. Also sent an email to HikCentral CS.

Thank you!

Tried to do exactly as the docs said, Investigated here in stackoverflow (only 1 related question), ChatGPT and still getting the same repnose.